# Should I use a semicolon or a comma when listing the features of a room?

Tags: word-usage, punctuation

I have two options:

> Features: Hot water; Cold water;

or

> Features: Hot water, Cold water

Can someone explain why I should perhaps use one of these instead of the other. I have looked for more information on this but what I find so far only really applies to clauses and not to one or two word strings.

Answer (score 3):

You would use the semicolon to prevent ambiguities but I see no room for possible ambiguities here. Stick to the comma if there is no reason to use the semicolon.